# removing previous date and after date

Tags: php

My problem is I need to remove the record for the date yesterday and tomorrow, for example. I will select June 2 and it will display june 1 to 3, I only need to display june 2, does anyone here has an experience doing that? I need it badly. Thanks in advance =) [image]

```
session_start();
include_once('dbr.php');
require('daily_summary_process123.php');

$id=$_SESSION['user_id'];
$flag = false;
if($id!=''){

    if($_GET['date1']!='' or $_GET['date2']!=''){

                $pnumber = $_GET['pnumber'];

        $sdate=$_GET['date1'];  
        $sdate=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($sdate. ' -1 day'));

        $edate=$_GET['date2'];  
        $edate=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($edate. ' +1 day'));

         $sql="SELECT ".
                    "vehicle_id,pnumber,Date as xdate,Time as xtime,OFFSET,".
                    "Street1,Street2,Region,City,".
                    "`Engine` AS es,`door` AS ds,`emergency` AS em,`call` AS cs,speed,".
                    "latitude lat,longitude lng,idling_limit ilimit,speed_limit slimit,Speed,offset,color,a.ID as xid,temp1 as tp1,temp2 as tp2, temp3 as tp3 ".
                "FROM ".
                    "vehiclelog a " .
                "INNER JOIN  ".
                    "user_vehicle b ".
                "ON ".
                    "a.PNumber = b.plate_number ".
                "INNER JOIN ".
                    "vehicle c ".
                "ON ".
                    "b.plate_number = c.plate_number ".
                "WHERE ".
                    "b.user_id=".$id." ".
                "AND ".
                    "b.plate_number='".$pnumber."' ".
                "AND Date>='".$sdate."' and Date<='".$edate."'".
                " ORDER BY ".
                    "concat(Date,' ',Time) ";

        $data = mysql_magic($sql);
        echo json_encode(processData($data));
    }   
}
```

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you need to display the date between the two input dates? For e.g June 2 in this case?

Comment: I hope i understand you correctly, but if you delete the '=' in your query where you use the date like this: "AND Date>'".$sdate."' and Date<'".$edate."'".   Does this help ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you need to display the date between the two input dates?

For e.g: When inputs are June 1 and June 3 we should display June 2.

In that case, you can simply replace >= with > and <= with < sign.

```
"AND Date > '".$sdate."' and Date < '".$edate."'".
```

Comment: Don't steal my answer, haha :P

Answer (score 0):

What they say was true Cyril change operator from >= 'greater than and equal to' to 'greater than' and <= 'less than and equal to' to 'less than' but still it depends on the format of date/time, sometimes you need to convert it. but for accurate answer please provide the exact value of date or the format of the column date.

Edit. Try replacing AND to OR